# Inconsistent definition of word boundary at bash keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: bash

Default shortcuts should be

> - Alt + d   ==> Delete the Word after the cursor.
> - Ctrl + w  ==>  Cut the Word before the cursor to the clipboard.

---

The command line is `ls /tmp/dir/a.doc -al`

Cursor at `c`.  Press 'ctrl-w'. The line is now `ls c -al`.  So `/tmp/dir/a.doc` is one word.  Word boundary is at `space`.

Cursor at `t`.  Press 'alt-d'.  The line is now `ls //dir/a.doc -al`.  So `tmp` is one word.  Word boundary is at `/`.

---

Why are they inconsistent?

This was tested on a live disk Linux distro so no shortcuts are altered.

bash 5.0.17(1)

Comment: _Cursor at c. Press 'ctrl-w'. The line is now ls  -al_ - for me it changes to `ls c -al` on GNU bash, version 5.0.18(1)-release (x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu)